# Дата в mysql преобразовать

Tags: mysql, база-данных

в базе дата храниться вот так 1532360691
как мне в запросе сразу преобразовать ее в нормальную дату?
так что-то не работает

```
SELECT mp.id from modx_ms2_products as mp left join modx_site_content ms on ms.id = mp.id where ms.parent =".$parent." and DATE_FORMAT(ms.`createdon`, '%d.%m.%Y') = '".date('d.m.Y')."'
```

Comment: from_unixtime(). но для сравнения было бы лучше сравнивать колонку как есть, а для этого привести константу с которой сравниваете unix_timestamp(). И что то мне подсказывает, что вот то `date('d.m.Y')` это текущая дата, которую в mysql возвращает now(), но конечно в виде datetime, так что `unix_timestamp()`. А вообще не надо хранить дату в БД в виде unixtime с ней работать жутко неудобно

Comment: хотя вы хотите сравнить день, без времени, так что я бы в итоге написал `createdon >= unix_timestamp(curdate()) and createdon < unix_timestamp(curdate()+interval 1 day)`. И да, как видите в MySQL еще можно спокойно прибавлять вычитать время в любых единицах, если оно в виде datetime конечно

Comment: спасибо, второй вариант сработал